# What is the proper way to save a resource in an @Async task?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

I am trying to update a resource inside an asynchronous thread that repeats its task until  cancelled.  I am using Future to store the thread in a hashmap so it can be cancelled at a later time.  The thread forks as expected, and the object instance within the Async method changes its values fine, but when I try to commit them, the changes are not reflected in the DB, and I cannot see any error messages on the console.  I've tried many different combinations of @Async and @Transactional but still haven't gotten it.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help!

RoomService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class RoomService {

@Inject private FooService fooService;
...

public Future<String> startRoom(Room room) {
    Future<String> future = fooService.startFoo(room.getId());
    map.put(room.getId(), future);
    return future;
}
```

FooService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooService {

...

public void save(Foo foo) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(foo);
}

@Async
public Future<String> startFoo(int id) {
    Foo foo = getFooById(id);
    try {
        while (true) {
            foo.setName("Peter");
            save(foo);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    return new AsyncResult<String>("done");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you make your `@Async` method in a different class for which you create a bean and inject the `FooService`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks that seems to have done it!  Why does moving the Async method out of the service make it work?  Can you put your reply in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the `@Async` method be part of a `@Transactional` bean means Spring intercepts your method twice: once for `@Transactional` to wrap the method in a `Transaction` and once for `@Async` to execute the method in a separate `Thread`.

Because of the way [proxying works](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying), once you are inside a method of `FooService`, invoking
another method is done on the actual object, not on the proxy which has all the `@Transactional` behavior. As such, no new transaction is created/committed/rolled back. The actual `Transaction` boundary is the `@Async` method itself. But since your method executes an infinite loop, that commit will never happen.

I suggest you make your `@Async` method in a different class for which you create a bean and inject the `FooService`. This way, the `@Transactional` behavior is wrapping the actual call to

```
fooService.save(foo); // fooService is actually a proxy
```

and is therefore committed on each invocation.